# Can I transduce / educe over multiple collections without concatting them

Tags: clojure, transducer

Below is a bare-bones version of what I'm doing:

```
(eduction (map inc) (concat [1 2] [3 4]))
; -> (2 3 4 5)
```

Is there a way to get the same eduction, without having to pay the cost of `concat`, which creates an intermediate lazy seq?

The following would perhaps already be a bit less wasty, as instead of the lazy seq, we just have a vector, but I wonder if even that can be avoided.

```
(eduction (comp cat (map inc)) [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

Comment: There is almost zero cost to the lazy seq solution using `concat`, so I'm not sure why you don't just do that?

Comment: @AlanThompson `(not= almost-zero zero)` There are cases where you *need* to squeeze the last bit of performance out of your code. I'm in such a situation, where this code is in the hot path. Also, I'm simply curious. And although transducers are in my opinion mainly about DRY and decomplecting code, another aspect of them is superior performance.

Comment: I tend to agree with @AlanThompson here. If you find a more performant solution, could you please edit your post with https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium timings comparing the two ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be simplest to process your collections separately and combine the results. There is, in fact, an easy reducers-based solution that does exactly that under the covers.

The `clojure.core.reducers` namespace has [`cat`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core.reducers/cat), a combining function for `fold`, that you can repurpose to construct a reducible concatenation of your vectors.

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(eduction (map inc) (r/cat [1 2] [3 4]))
;; => (2 3 4 5)
```

This avoids the lazy sequence used in `concat`. If you have more than two vectors, you can concatenate them all with `(reduce r/cat [] colls)` or similar.

This approach did speed up some of the experiments I did, though not your particular example.

Comment: This goes to show that chunked (lazy) seqs are often fast enough, and the performance ‘improvement’ afforded by reducibles may not be there at all. Measure!

Comment: Thanks glts. I also timed this against small and large input collections, with the result that performance-wise it does not matter. Still interesting to know this function is there in core...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without the reducer just using the built in `cat` transducer

```
(eduction (comp cat (map inc)) [[1 2] [3 4]])
;; => (2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: If you read my question to the end, you'll find your suggestion in it - verbatim.